# How to use a parameter as a global variable in a .m file?

Tags: matlab

To describe clearly what I mean,
I just give an example here:

```
function y = f(x,a)
global a
y = f1(x);

function y = f1(x)
global a
y = x + a;
```

Here, I want the variable 'a' to be used as a global variable that can be called by the subfunction 'f1' to compute $x+a$. (My purpose is to reduce the transformation of parameters)

But this function does not work, unless I define a new variable 'b' to restore the value of 'a'.

The question is, how can I make 'a' a global variable directly, without defining a new variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend you to use global variables, especially since you pass a into the function `f`.

The behavior you want can be obtained without global variables, but using [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html):

```
function y = f(x,a)
y = f1(x);
   function y = f1(x)
   y = x + a;
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
a=evalin('base','a');
```

to get the value of `a` from the base workspace.  Global variables are generally discouraged.

Comment: With all due respect, that's even worse than just global variables. `eval`, `evalin` and `assignin` should only be used when no other options are feasible. Your solution will work, but the code will be a lot harder to maintain.

Comment: Yes, I agree in principle.  At some level the OP need to pass the value of `a` to the function.  My preference would be to pass it explicitly.